# Ocultar div no materialize css

Tags: css, bootstrap-3, layout-responsivo, materialize

Alguem aqui usar materialize css ? sabe se existe alguma forma de ocultar a coluna de uma tabela atraves de uma classe css ? no bootstrap tem como fazer isso usando isso class="visible-xs" fui na docs e nao achei... teria como ? ou vou ter que escrever essa regra ?

http://materializecss.com/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

O `Materializecss` tem as seguintes classes para te ajudar a esconder ou mostrar algum elemento de acordo com os breakpoints:

```
.hide   // Oculta em todos os breakpoints
.hide-on-small-only // Oculta no breakpoint small
.hide-on-med-only   // Oculta apenas no breakpoint medium
.hide-on-med-and-down  //Oculta no breakpoint medium e abaixo dele
.hide-on-med-and-up  // Oculta no breakpoint medium e acima dele
.hide-on-large-only // Oculta apenas no breakpoint large
.show-on-small  // Exibe no breakpoint small
.show-on-medium // Exibe no breakpoint medium
.show-on-large  // Exibe no breakpoint large
.show-on-medium-and-up  // Exibe no breakpoint a partir do medium
.show-on-medium-and-down  // Exibe no breakpoint abaixo do medium
```

http://materializecss.com/helpers.html